# persistent session variable after being unset then page redirected

Tags: php, session, header

let me start directly with the code where the issue can be demonstrated and reproduced:

```
<?php
session_start();
// the output
if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    assignSecret();
    echo "welcome ".$_SESSION["user"]."<br>";
    echo "your secret is ".$_SESSION["secret"];
}
else{
    echo "no one is signed";
}

// sign out mechanism
if(isset($_POST["signout"])){
    // yes I want to unset only the user and keep all other session details
    // it's a desired behaviour
    unset($_SESSION["user"]);
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit();
}
// sign in mechanism
if(isset($_POST["signin"])){
    $_SESSION["user"]="world";
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit();
}
// random BS
function assignSecret(){
    unset($_SESSION);
    // I actually reload session data from a database
    // but for the sake of simplificy let's assume:
    $_SESSION = ["user" => "world", "secret" => "xyz"];
}
?>

<!--All HTML stuff-->
<form method="post" action>
    <input type="submit" name="signin" value="sign in">
    <input type="submit" name="signout" value="sign out">
</form>
```

I can sign in fine, but when I click sign out, here is what I think the order of execution is (I used xdebug to confirm this):

1. `$_SESSION["user"]` is set and so `assignSecret()` is executed
2. `$_POST["signout"]` is also set and so `$_SESSION["user"]` gets unset
3. the script re-executes from the start because of `header()` function
4. at this point `$_SESSION["user"]` should be unset already, but it isn't, why ?

the expected result is for the signout to happen, no `$_SESSION["user"]` should be set any longer.
but that doesn't happen.

Comment: Pretty sure if you look at the error log you will see a message saying something along the lines of `"Headers Already Sent"`. That would be due to the output you are generating before issuing the `header()`  calls

Comment: I think the main problem here is the way you access the `$_SESSION` superglobal in `assignSecret()`. Don't use: `unset($_SESSION);`, use [session_destroy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), and don't assign an array to `$_SESSION` itself, but add values to the `$_SESSION` array like this: `$_SESSION["name"] = $value;`.